# Use PowerShell to scaffold arbitrary files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, scaffolding

Is there a scaffolding library for PowerShell that allows me to generate arbitrary files?

For example:

PowerShell functions:

```
<# 
.Synopsis 
...
#>
function __NAME__ () {
  [CmdLetBinding()]
  Params()
  Begin {}
  Process {}
  End {}
}
```

SQL scripts:

```
/*
Author:  __AUTHOR__
Revisions:
  <%= Get-Date -DisplayHint date %> - __INITIALS__ - created
*/
__QUERY__
```

Features:

- accessible from PowerShell
- installed via a package manager (e.g. PsGet, Chocolaty)
- supports tokens (e.g. `__AUTHOR__`) and embedded statements (e.g. `Get-Date -DisplayHint date`)
- uses controller files (e.g. `ps-script.ps1`,`sql-script.ps1`) and templates (`ps-script.ps1.template`,`sql-script.sql.template`)
- includes some measure of template self-discovery (i.e. files located in template directory, perhaps)
- easily invoked from PowerShell `PS> scaffold sql-script @{"author"="John Doe"; "initials="JD"}`

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried [PowerShell Scaffolding](https://gist.github.com/trayburn/5558458) myself but psake is great and from the examples from the link, it should cover most of the features you wish for.

You could also use nodejs from powershell with [node-scaffold](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-scaffold).